# Class in autoloaded file not recognized

Tags: composer-php

The class definition of `\MyOrganization\OurLibrary\Application` isn't recognized in a script in a framework package that uses the core library. It *is* recognized in an exact copy of the script in the core folder. What is the problem, and how do I resolve it?

**library/core/Application.php**

```
namespace MyOrganization\OurLibrary;
class Application {
    public static function someMethod() ...
}
```

**library/core/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "myorganization/core",
  "type": "library",
  "config": { "secure-http": false },
  "require": { ... }
  "require-dev": { ... }
  "autoload": {
     "files": ["Application.php"],
  }
}
```

**library/framework/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "myorganization/framework",
    "type": "library",
    "require": { 
        "myorganization/core": "dev-master",
        ...
    },
    "require-dev": { ... }
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../core",
            "options": { "symlink": true }
        }
    ]
}
```

**library/(core|framework)/script.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
\MyOrganization\OurLibrary\Application::someMethod();
```

Comment: did you `composer install` in the folder framework? I get your exact example working, from my side.

Comment: Yes I did `composer install` in the folder framework.

Comment: What is your composer version? And on what OS are your running it (*nux, windows, Mac, other)?

Comment: Composer 1.9.0 on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Ah, my test was on 1.8. Will have a second look at it.

Comment: After multiple rounds of running Composer and making various changes to the code, including deleting a bad link, it apparently works now.

Comment: Voting to close, then as this looks your issue is not reproducible anymore